# dart sync* Iterable is only called when Iterable is consumed

Tags: dart

I made this piece of code and it is not doing what I would expect. I hope someone can clarify if this is common behavior, or if I should report a bug.

```dart
void main() async {
  final stream = makeStream();
  print('printing and using the stream');
  for(var v in stream) {
    print(v);
  }
}

Iterable<int> makeStream() sync* {
  print('making a stream');
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    yield 25;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
printing and using the stream
making a stream
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
```

I would expect that calling the `makeStream` function would first print 'making a stream' and only return on `yield`. But instead it seems that the function is postponed until the `for` actually constructs the `Iterable`.

Considering this function `async` would make it a different story, but for a `sync*` function I would expect that all code before the `yield` is actually executed.

Comment: The entire point of iterators is that they are lazy, so values are only calculated when they are used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generator code is syntactic sugar. What your `makeStream` function is doing under the hood is not going to resemble your code at all. To illustrate this point, this is your code:

```dart
Iterable<int> makeStream() sync* {
  print('making a stream');
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    yield 25;
  }
}

void main() {
  final stream = makeStream();
  print('printing and using the stream');
  for(var v in stream) {
    print(v);
  }
}
```

And this is what that code looks like when compiled to Javascript:

```js
var A = {
  // ...
  makeStream() {
    return new A._SyncStarIterable(A.makeStream$body(), type$._SyncStarIterable_int);
  },
  makeStream$body() {
    return function() {
      var $async$goto = 0, $async$handler = 1, $async$currentError, i;
      return function $async$makeStream($async$iterator, $async$errorCode, $async$result) {
        if ($async$errorCode === 1) {
          $async$currentError = $async$result;
          $async$goto = $async$handler;
        }
        while (true)
          switch ($async$goto) {
            case 0:
              // Function start
              A.print("making a stream");
              i = 0;
            case 2:
              // for condition
              if (!(i < 10)) {
                // goto after for
                $async$goto = 4;
                break;
              }
              $async$goto = 5;
              return $async$iterator._current = 25, 1;
            case 5:
              // after yield
            case 3:
              // for update
              ++i;
              // goto for condition
              $async$goto = 2;
              break;
            case 4:
              // after for
              // implicit return
              return 0;
            case 1:
              // rethrow
              return $async$iterator._datum = $async$currentError, 3;
          }
        };
      };
    },
  },
  main() {
    var t1, t2, t3,
      stream = A.makeStream();
    A.print("printing and using the stream");
    for (t1 = stream.$ti, t2 = new A._SyncStarIterator(stream._outerHelper(), t1._eval$1("_SyncStarIterator<1>")), t1 = t1._precomputed1; t2.moveNext$0();) {
      t3 = t2._current;
      A.printString(A.S(t3 == null ? t1._as(t3) : t3));
    }
  },
};
```

*(Greatly truncated for brevity and `async` removed from `main` for simplicity)*

As you can see, there is a lot going on here. What's basically happening is that your generator function is getting converted into a state machine that gets wrapped inside a specially-designed `Iterable` class. That `Iterable` is then invoked by an `Iterator` in the `main` function which controls walking through each iteration of the loop and returning the result at each step.

So to answer your question, the reason `"printing and using the stream"` appears before `"making a stream"` is because the former exists within that state machine and doesn't get called until that state machine is fired up for the first time by the `Iterator`, whereas the latter is part of the normal execution of the main code.